Generators of a group and normal subgroups
Can we say anything about a minimal generating set of a finite group based on its normal subgroups? For example, can we bound their order, or say whether they come from the same conjugacy class?
An easy example is that when $G$ is cyclic, if $x$ generates $G$ then $x$ does not generate any (normal) subgroup of $G$.
If it isn't possible in general to relate a minimal set of generators of a finite group to its normal subgroups, can we do this when $G$ is generated by only 2 or 3 elements?

One cannot talk about the generators of a group. For instance, one can take the entire group as a generating set.

It is corrected.

Every finite simple group is generated by two elements. There is an extensive research on this. Maybe if you have only a few normal subgroups one might be able to restrict the number of generators?

Please do not post simultaneously here and in math.stackexchange. Especially if you do not alert readers of the double post.

math.stackexchange copy has been deleted on that site.

I should add that for a $p$-group if you have $k$ normal subgroups, then in particular, you have at most $k$ maximal normal subgroups, Thus, if $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup, then $G/Phi(G)$ has at most $k$ maximal subspaces, so its dimension, which is also the number of generators, is at most about $\log_p k$ (I am too tired now to figure out the $\pm 1$).

Just to stick in an example that I find mildly surprising: A direct product of 19 copies of $A_5$ can be generated by two elements, but a direct product of 20 copies needs three generators.

The arXiv paper The Minimum Generating Set Problem by Lucchini and Thakkar (to be published in Journal of Algebra) describes an algorithm for finding a smallest-sized generating set of (a finite group) $G$ starting from a chief series $G = N_u > N_{u-1} > \dotsb N_1 > N_0= \{1\}$ of $G$.
The idea is to successively find smallest-sized generating sets of the quotients $G/N_{u-1}, G/N_{u-2},\dotsc,G/N_1,G/N_0 \cong G$. The top factor is simple and either cyclic with one generator, or nonabelian simple with two generators, which can quickly found by a random search.
Defining $d(G)$ to be the smallest size of a generating set of $G$, there is a useful result that, for a minimal normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, we always have $d(G/N) \le d(G) \le d(G/N)+1$ and, furthermore, if $d(G/N) = d$ with $G/N = \langle g_1N,\ldots,g_dN\rangle$, then either $d(G) = d(G/N)$ and there exist $n_1,\dotsc,n_d \in N$ with $G = \langle g_1n_1,\dotsc,g_dn_d \rangle$; or $d(G) = d(G/N)+1$ and there exist $n_1,\dotsc,n_d,n_{d+1} \in N$ with $G = \langle g_1n_1,\dotsc,g_dn_d,n_{d+1} \rangle$.
The bulk of the paper is describing methods to decide which of the two cases we are in when moving from $G/N_i$ to $G/N_{i-1}$ without recourse to too many exhaustive searches through all $d$- or ($d+1$)-tuples of elements of $N$. Implementations run very fast in practice.

Does it mean that $d(G)$ is bounded by something linear in the number of normal groups because $u$ is bounded by the number of normal subgroups? Is that best?

@YiftachBarnea Yes it clearly implies that $d(G)$ is bounded by the length of a chief series, and that bound is attained in an elementary abelian group, for example. There could be a better bound in terms of the number of normal subgroups.

Let me improve my comment above. Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group generated by $d$ elements. Let $\Phi(G)=G^p[G,G]$ be its Frattini subgroup. Then $G/\Phi(G)$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group of order $p^d$, that is, a vector space of dimension $d$ over a field of $p$ elements. The number of subspaces in such vector space is about $p^{d^2/4}$ (see somewhere in Chapter 1 of Subgroup Growth by Lubotzky and Segal). Each such subspace corresponds to distinct normal subgroup of $G$. Thus, if $n(G)$ is the number of normal subgroups of $G$, we get that $n(G) \geq p^{d^2/4}$ or in other words $2\sqrt{\log_p(n(G))} \geq d$.
Notice that the best bound is achieved for elementary abelian $p$-group.
It seems natural to ask what can be done for finite soluble groups and more generally for any finite group.

I would conjecture that $d(G) = O(\log n(G))$ for general finite groups $G$, and it might  be possible to prove it.

@DerekHolt I guess the most obvious example is direct sum of the same simple group, say $A_5$. Both the number of generators and the number of normal subgroups grows very slowly with the number of components. I am too tired now to think about it, but it might give an interesting example.

For a finite nonabelian simple group $S$ there is a bound $d(S^n) \le 2 + \log_{60} n$ due to Wiegold, which supports my conjecture. I am not sure whether there is a known  lower bound - there probably is.

@DerekHolt so $n(S^k)=2^k$ so we actually get something like $\log \log n(S^k)$ is about $d(S^k)$. Much better than your conjecture. Possibly $p$-groups are the worst case.
